# How to refactor dynamic SQL to static SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been working with the dynamic SQL at the following location https://fullparam.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/fck-it-i-am-going-to-search-all-tables-all-collumns/

The query works perfectly, but it's very slow. I was told that it's slow because it's using dynamic SQL.

I tried to refactor the dynamic SQL to static, but I keep getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
> Incorrect syntax near ','

Can someone take a look at the cod and let me know how to fix it?

```
DECLARE @SearchStrColumnValue nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @FullRowResult bit
DECLARE @FullRowResultRows int

SET @SearchStrColumnValue = 'IMA3DAA' -- use LIKE syntax
SET @FullRowResult = 1
SET @FullRowResultRows = 3

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #Results

CREATE TABLE #Results 
(
    TableName nvarchar(128),
    ColumnName nvarchar(128),
    ColumnValue nvarchar(max),
    ColumnType nvarchar(20)
)

SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Fetch table names and column names
INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue, ColumnType)
SELECT 
    c.TABLE_NAME,
    c.COLUMN_NAME,
    CASE 
        WHEN c.DATA_TYPE = 'xml' THEN LEFT(CAST(t.[value] AS nvarchar(MAX)), 4096)
        WHEN c.DATA_TYPE = 'timestamp' THEN master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(c.COLUMN_NAME)
        ELSE LEFT(c.COLUMN_NAME, 4096)
    END,
    c.DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t ON c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
WHERE c.DATA_TYPE IN (
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@SearchStrColumnValue, '%', ''), '_', ''), '[', ''), ']', ''), '-', '')) = 1 
    THEN 'tinyint', 'int', 'smallint', 'bigint', 'numeric', 'decimal', 'smallmoney', 'money'
    ELSE ''
    END, 'char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'timestamp', 'uniqueidentifier'
)
AND (COALESCE(@SearchStrTableName, c.TABLE_NAME) IS NULL OR c.TABLE_NAME LIKE COALESCE(@SearchStrTableName, c.TABLE_NAME))
AND (COALESCE(@SearchStrColumnName, c.COLUMN_NAME) IS NULL OR c.COLUMN_NAME LIKE COALESCE(@SearchStrColumnName, c.COLUMN_NAME))

SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue, ColumnType, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM #Results
GROUP BY TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue, ColumnType
```

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` the statement first. Then you can debug that SQL and solve the problem before propagating the solution to your SQL that generates the dynamic statement. Often you'll find that the problems are quite simple, such as a typographical error that is difficult to spot in the literal strings; for example a missing whitespace/linebreak, or leading/trailing delimiters. Taking the time to get the non-dynamic statement working first is really important, as if that doesn't work the dynamic one will have no chance of working correctly.

Comment: Hi @ThomA, thanks for reaching out. It would appear the issue is with my case statement. But I can't see the error

Comment: It's a `CASE` expression, and in your `WHERE` you are trying to return multiple values; you can't do that. A `CASE` expression returns a single scalar value.

Comment: @ThomA, I think I understand what you're saying, however I'm not sure how to go about making the change.

Comment: Use `AND`/`OR` logic instead. `WHERE ((<Boolean Expression> AND <Boolean IN Expression>) OR (<Boolean Expression> AND <Boolean IN Expression>))`

Comment: @ThomA, can you modify the code where I need to make the change please?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use static SQL for such a query, and static SQL isn't any faster.

Your primary issue appears to be the use of `LIKE` against many different types of columns. `LIKE` should only be used against text columns, not number, binary or other types.

Also:

- Don't use `WHILE` just to avoid a `CURSOR` it doesn't speed things up. What does help is doing everything set-based, so using a `STRING_AGG` query or similar. This will be much faster.
- Use `sys.tables` not `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, which is for compatibility only.
- Don't use `NOLOCK`, it has serious integrity implications.
- Don't use `ISNUMERIC`, instead use `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST`
- Don't use `fn_varbintohexstr` instead just `CAST` the binary values if you really needed to.
- You need to specify the table schema also.
- Pass through the value as an actual parameter, not by injecting it.
- Object and column names should be of `sysname` type.

```sql
DECLARE @SearchStrInXML bit = 0; /* Searching XML data may be slow */
DECLARE @SearchStrSchemaName sysname = NULL; /* NULL for all tables, uses LIKE syntax */
DECLARE @SearchStrTableName sysname = NULL; /* NULL for all tables, uses LIKE syntax */
DECLARE @SearchStrColumnName sysname = NULL; /* NULL for all columns, uses LIKE syntax */
DECLARE @SearchStrColumnValue nvarchar(255) = 'IMA3DAA'; -- use LIKE syntax



DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT
  ' + QUOTENAME(s.name, '''') + ' + ' + QUOTENAME(t.name, '''') + ' AS TableName,
  ' + QUOTENAME(c.name, '''') + ' AS ColumnName,
  CAST(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' AS nvarchar(max)) AS ColumnValue
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + '
WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) +
      CASE WHEN typ.name IN (
        'tinyint', 'int', 'smallint', 'bigint', 'numeric', 'decimal', 'smallmoney', 'money', 'timestamp', 'uniqueidentifier'
        ) THEN ' =' ELSE ' LIKE' END +
     ' TRY_CONVERT(' + typ.name + ', @value)'
  AS nvarchar(max)), N'
UNION ALL
'
    )
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.types typ ON typ.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE (t.name LIKE @SearchStrTableName OR @SearchStrTableName IS NULL)
  AND (s.name LIKE @SearchStrSchemaName OR @SearchStrSchemaName IS NULL)
  AND (c.name LIKE @SearchStrColumnName OR @SearchStrColumnName IS NULL)
  AND (
    typ.name IN (
      'tinyint', 'int', 'smallint', 'bigint', 'numeric', 'decimal', 'float', 'real', 'smallmoney', 'money', 'char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'timestamp', 'uniqueidentifier'
    )
    OR @SearchStrInXML = 1 AND typ.name = 'xml'
  );

SET @sql += '
OPTION (RECOMPILE);'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@value nvarchar(255)',
  @value = @SearchStrColumnValue;
```

Comment: thanks for reaching out. I tried your code, but I'm getting the following errors ```Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 39
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 42
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".```

Comment: isn't it better to build a select by avoiding UNION ALL per table/column combo, and instead build a long WHERE for each column per table once. This way, you probably just gonna scan a table once instead of once per column. Although, perhaps sql server already can optimize and only scan once

Comment: @Charlieface, the code appeared to work fine on one of our databases. On the other databases I'm getting the error ```Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 253
Explicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to sql_variant is not allowed.```

Comment: Do you want/need to search your `MAX` length columns as well, @Patterson ?

Comment: @Patterson OK you could change the cast to `nvarchar(max)` instead of `sql_variant`. But that may mean the results look a bit odd depending on how it's casted.

Comment: @Charlieface, I will try changing to nvarchar(max), and see if that works

Comment: @siggemannen No it can't optimize that. But the reason I did this is that it needs separate row results per column. I could probably have unpivoted it, but couldn't be bothered.

Comment: @Charlieface, changing sql_variant to nvarchar(max) did the trick. Thank you